# Return string.Format error

Tags: java

I am getting this error: - **The method Format(String, int, int, int) is undefined for the 
 type String"**

Can u please help me with this? I have tried all other venues for understanding this error.

```
Public class Time {

private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;

public void setTime(int h,int m, int s){
    hour = ((h >=0 && h<24)? h:0);
    minute = ((m >=0 && m<60)? m:0);
    second = ((s >=0 && s<60)? s:0);
}
public String toMilitary() {
    return String.Format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Java is case sensitive, you want to use [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) (starts with lowercase **f**):

```
return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute,second);
```

This also applies for `Public`, which should be `public` (starts with lowercase **p**).